# Multiupload of files using flash uploader and php and saving into mysql database

Tags: php, flash, multi-upload

I want to develop a backend admin solution to save images for a post using some multiupload flash uploader. I mean that kind o f uploader, where when you click on browse and than in the open dialogue box you can choodse mulitple files using CTRL plus LEFT MOUSE CLICK).

I would like to save every new image to the database. With saving I mean, creating a new row for every item(image) in my table called images:

```
1.id (automatically increasing)
2.file_name
3.user_who_uploaded_that_book
```

I would like also to limit the number of files that can a user uplaod (e.g. max 20 files) somewhere in the config file.

Comment: Please ask only one question at once. Also add your code. Looking for scripts is out of the scope of this site, so I removed that part.

Comment: As far as the code goes I need an advice about that. I do not know how to deal with multiuploads in controller and model part, maybe a link to some tutorial will be enough for me.

Comment: reading this may help you http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf8.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ce9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'm a fan of [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which include a nice set of examples on how to set it up for multiple files upload. It also includes an upload.php script, as example for backend setup.

HTML4 doesn't support multiple selection of files, so you need to rely on either HTML5 or extension (like flash or silverlight) for that. Plupload supports all of the above, so it should save you some legwork.

Comment: Plupload is the best multi-file uploader I've used. `+1up`

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got 2 basic questions here:

1. How to select local files for upload via flash?
2. How to send multiple files to server as POST?

For #1 You need to use [flash.net.FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html).

For #2 There's no built-in 'Multipart' loader in flash, which I'm pretty sure is what you need. The best one I've found is by this genius developer named Eugene: http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=198. This works great, though personally had I've some issues with the onComplete handler in IE8 & IE9. I'm sure it's IE's fault and not Eugene's. I worked around this my listening for the HTTPStatusEvent event like so:

```
var ml:MultipartURLLoader = new MultipartURLLoader();           
ml.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onHTTPStatusEvent);
ml.addVariable('Content-Type', "image/png");
ml.addFile(pngStream, filename, "file", "image/png");
ml.load('http://...');
function onHTTPStatusEvent( event: HTTPStatusEvent ){           
    if(stat == 0 || (stat >= 200 && stat < 205)){
        //upload success
    }else{
        //some kinda error
    }
}
```

(This should work with multiple addFiles(_);)

I'm also listening for the standard events:

```
ml.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadComplete);
ml.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, uploadProgress);
```

But haven't been able to get PROGRESS to work at all, and COMPLETE doesn't fire on IE... Anyone know any alternatives that work on IE? Eugene's code is working for me now, but I don't think I can add a "uploading..." progress bar as it is... which would be cool.